# Using dictionary for sum of values from a text file from multiple rows and columns

Tags: c#

I have text data in format of:

```
OrderID:100,ItemID:1,Price:1000 //Row1
OrderID:101,ItemID:2,Price:200  //Row2
OrderID:102,ItemID:3,Price:100  //Row3
```

I need the `Totalitems:3` and `totalPrice:1300` and I don't know which way to get an output for this problem using `Indexof` to access or something else

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please [edit] and add your code. Where is the issue? Reading the file? Splitting the lines? Adding the totals?

Comment: If you had this is proper JSON it would be much simpler `{"OrderID":100,"ItemID":1,"Price":1000}`. As it is, you can use something like `LinesOfText.Select(l => int.Parse(l.Split(',')[2])).Sum()`

Comment: uh, weird, i see 3 items (100, 101, 102).. why did the `Totalitems` 4?

Answer (score 1):

One way is to first read all the lines from the file with `File.ReadAllLines(fileName)`. Then you can loop through the lines and parse out and aggregate the information you need.

```cs
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(fileName);

int totalItems = 0;
decimal totalPrice = 0;

foreach (var line in lines)
{
    var columns = line.Split(',');
    var priceColumn = columns[2];
    var price = decimal.Parse(priceColumn.Split(':')[1]);

    totalItems++;
    totalPrice += price;
}

Console.WriteLine($"Total items: {totalItems}");
Console.WriteLine($"Total price: {totalPrice}");
```

For more complex CSV files or more advanced features, you can look at [CsvHelper](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CsvHelper), which has worked well for me.

Comment: @John_Martin Please consider accepting the answer if this solves your question.

Comment: it did help, thanks.. have a doubt--I have 4 rows:

--ID:101,Cost:100 //row1 --ID:101,Cost:10 //row2 --ID:102,Cost:5 //row3 --ID:102,Cost:2 //row4

I want to know how to get sum for 101 Id and then for Id 102

Comment: In that case, you would probably benefit from storing all the data in classes to act upon. Then you could use LINQ to do something like `orderItems.Where(o => o.OrderId == 102).Sum(o => o.Price)`. If you have further questions unrelated to the original post, please post a new question.

Answer (score 0):

```
// parse the price
const string sep = ",Price:";    

// initial tuple for sum&count, aka "seed"            
(decimal sum, int count) = (0,0); 

var lines  = File.ReadAllLines(someCsvFilePath);
var result = lines.Aggregate((sum, count),
        (curr, line) => line?.IndexOf(sep) is {} pos and > -1
                     && decimal.TryParse(line.Substring(pos + sep.Length), out var prc)
                      ? (curr.sum + prc, curr.count + 1) : curr);

Console.WriteLine("Sum: {0:N0}, TotalItems: {1:N0}", result.sum, result.count);
```